# finding formulas for degree sequences of a grid graph

Tags: graph-theory

What I know:
$G_{m,n}$ is a graph with $m*n$ vertices; it is a grid of $n$ rows with length $m$ or vice versa; one has edges between consecutive vertices in each row & column.

Problem:
For $G_{m,n}$ , $m$ & $n$ are both greater than $1$.
degree sequence: $4^a 3^b 2^c$                <--- I already know that $c=4$ because $a$ and $b$ are both greater than $1$; I also know that $a+b+c=m*n$.

Find formulas for $a$ and $b$ in terms of $m$ and $n$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how $c=4$ follows from $a$ and $b$ both being greater than $1$. I get the impression that you're approaching this in a more complicated manner than is necessary. If you draw the grid for some specific small values of $m$ and $n$, you'll see that the four corners have degree $2$, the remaining vertices on the borders have degree $3$, and the rest have degree $4$. Those with degree $4$ form a rectangle of $(m-2)(n-2)$ vertices. Subtracting that and $4$ from $mn$ gives you the number of vertices with degree $3$.